# Prove an inequality of a convex differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [-1/2,1/2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex and differentable function. I need to show $$f(0)\leq \int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx.$$

We use the fact that in case $f$ is convex and differentiable, then $f(x_1)\geq f(x_2)+f'(x_2)(x_1-x_2).$ If one integrates both sides after rearrangement of the terms and sets $x_2=0$, this results into $$\int_{\frac{-1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} \,\,dx\geq f(0).$$

Is this correct? How I can go from here ? Can somebody provide a solution proposal or a suggestion ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c$ be a subderivative of $f$ at $x=0$, that is to say a number such that $f(x)\ge f(0) + c x = g(x)$. Then
\begin{equation}
\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}f(x) d x\ge  \int_{-0.5}^{0.5}g(x) d x 
= \left[f(0)x + c \frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{-0.5}^{0.5}
=f(0)
\end{equation}
It follows that convexity suffices, differentiability is not necessary.

Second proof without using differentiability:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}f(x) d x
= \int_{0}^{0.5}(f(x)+f(-x)) d x
\ge \int_0^{0.5} 2 f(0)d x = f(0)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks. I do not understand what do you mean by subderivative and how you come to the result. I need to use $f$ is differentiable as assumption.

Comment: Then take $c=f'(0)$

Comment: Is the expression I wrote wrong ? It looks similar to yours.

Comment: It is the same expression. Your mistake is to divide by $x$ before integrating.

Comment: How did you get your inequality ? It must somehow be related to the condition of convexity. But I do not see how.

Comment: Which inequality don't you understand?

Comment: It is about the inequality $f(x)\ge f(0) + c x = g(x)$.

Comment: Prove that if $f$ is convex in the interval $I$, then the (slope) function $x\mapsto\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ is monotonic increasing on $I\setminus x_0$. Then read the definition of a subderivative here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative